# How can i find total number of login in Django application by user?

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-models, django-rest-framework

In Django User table we can check last_login,
But I want to check the total number of login in the month by the user.

Is that any function where I can use directly in my system.

OR

Am I need to make a change on login view, when every-time user will log in then I can create an entry in Django Model?

I want to data like this:

```
Users   JunLogin  FebLogin
Virat    10         30
Sachin   9          11
```

Please suggest me the best way.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1):

You can take advantage of [Django signals](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/signals/) and connect to [the login signal](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/auth/#module-django.contrib.auth.signals)

and store the information you need in a separate model.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make a separate model to store these details:

```
class LoginDetails(models.Model):
    user_id = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    login_time = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now(), blank=False)

#Query to calculate the users login count 
from django.db.models import Count
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
last_month = datetime.today() - timedelta(days=30)

login_details = LoginDetails.objects.filter(my_date__gte=last_month).values('user_id').annotate(total=Count('user_id'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Django doesn't provide any API for this purpose.

There might be some tricky ways like counting the sessions to a user and you probably get how many logins they have but still, if your sessions expire, then you will lose data.

The best way would be adding a logger to your login view to count for each successful login.

It won't take many resources and yet it will yield some useful information.

Comment: I'm thinking same as you said

Answer (score 0):

not any method available. you can create table in which when user login that time  you increment count by one .